# Crown and Succession laws in recreated titles

Tags: crusader-kings-2

If I recreate a kingdom title that was destroyed, what level of crown authority does it return at?  Automatically at low?  Or whatever level it was at when it was destroyed?

Same for the succession scheme.  Does it default to Gavelkind or something like that, or does it keep whatever system it had upon destruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created titles should match laws with your existing primary title, though if you don't have a kingdom yet, your first will be autonomous vassals/free investure.

I've abused that by creating a new kingdom, increasing its crown laws, changing it to primary, destroying the older kingdom, and then recreating the older one to match laws. Thus allowing 2 crown law changes in a generation rather than only 1 at the cost of [50 opinion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139381/whats-the-benefit-of-destroying-titles). Mainly useful for small or titular kingdoms.

On the other hand usurped titles of the same rank keep their old laws (can easily screw up your succession plans if you're not careful with those).

Comment: So that's exactly what happened, I usurped another kingdom (Lithuania) that had Gavelkind succession and Low Crown Authority.  Horrified (my primary had Primogeniture after much struggle), I raised Lithuania's crown laws to medium, switched succession to seniority and then destroyed the title.  So you're saying now if I recreate Lithuania, it'll match my primary title's laws even though that's not what Lithuania had upon destruction?

Comment: Yep, that should happen for it's crown laws (authority/investiture/taxes/levies). However, I don't believe succession laws  are forced to update if the title already existed. Not sure.

Comment: It does appear that the succession laws are also updated on recreate.