# How does succession work in a tanistry empire?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I was King of Eire, and I've created the Empire of Alba.

I was surprised to notice that the Kingdom of Eire and the Empire of Alba have two separate successors.

What happens when I die, if two different kinsman get voted? I guess I would have the Empire, but **can I have an Empire without having a Kingdom, and having a Duchy (Mide) inside that Kingdom itself**?

*(sure, I could just [destroy the kingdoms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139381/whats-the-benefit-of-destroying-titles?rq=1), but that's beside the point of this question)*

*I also have the Kingdom of Wales, I've not created the Kingdom of Alba/Scotland, and while I control most of England and I'm sometimes voted to be heir of England, it's still independent.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kingdom will go to whoever it gets elected to, and you'll keep the empire with the king as a vassal under you. After the initial creation of an empire, there is no requirement saying you need to continue to hold a kingdom title. Even without owning the Kingdom of Wales this would be true. It is perfectly possible to be the Emperor of X without being the King of anything.

So basically you'll have one empire, one kingdom, one duchy, and one likely pretty pissed off vassal king. Better hope he's not ambitious.

Comment: While the Kingdom remains in your dynasty, there's a decent chance that it will pass back to your character or your heir, especially if you have an especially long-lived emperor. However, while the Kingdom is not in your direct control, it's likely to undergo a revolt or voluntary change in succession laws, giving the AI's further opportunities to screw up your dynasty.