# Ruling an empire of duchies

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I currently have the Empire of Hispania with all of its de jure kingdoms, as well as most of France's kingdoms and a few in Britain. I currently hold most of the kingdom titles personally and wanted to do some major restructuring, mainly in regards to instituting Imperial rule.

With the Imperial organization, will my Duke vassals still desire my appropriate Kingdom title, even though Imperial de-emphasizes inheritance anyway?

What if I make so my Dukes are of the burgher class, rather than the noble class, making so it is impossible for them to hold kingdoms?

With Imperial organization, does the limit of Duchy/County titles that can be held by burghers still apply? It doesn't say it doesn't, but it doesn't seem like it should given the lack of inheritance.

If that limit does still apply, forcing me to have many of my vassal dukes be nobility, and they still desire my Kingdoms even with Imperial organization, should I destroy my Kingdom titles? Is there any negative effect besides less monthly prestige?

Is there any penalty to making so that each of my Dukes have completely random county holdings to severely curb their power? I won't hold their de jure counties myself, only my other dukes will. I'm not sure if there is a benefit to this either as when you raise a Duke's levy, it appears in one place and I'm not sure if it works the same when they raise their levies against you.

Lastly, with Imperial organization, does the granting a Duchy opinion bonus still apply even though there is no longer a penalty for revocation?

Comment: You are asking several questions here, which may reduce the answers you receive. I will say that if your dukes have 'completely random' county holdings (some dukes hold counties in another duke's duchy) they will plot against each other, even if they can't make war. This could get a useful duke killed for no reason.

Comment: [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/139381/whats-the-benefit-of-destroying-titles?rq=1) relates to your question of destroying kingdom titles, and the answer mentions -50 opinion hit for 10 years within the destroyed kingdom

Comment: It is not impossible for burghers/clerics to HOLD kingdom titles. You can't grant them kingdoms, but they can gain them through other means (such as conquest).

Comment: Upvoting, because you ask good questions. But you really should break it up into separate questions.